# What happens if I add the same target/action to a gesture multiple times?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uicontrol

Am I asking for trouble if I add the same target/action pair to a `UIGestureRecognizer` -- or `UIControl` for that matter -- multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

from the apple documentation about `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method:

> You may call this method multiple times, and you may specify multiple
>   target-action pairs for a particular event. The action message may
>   optionally include the sender and the event as parameters, in that
>   order. When you call this method, target is not retained.

It seems you can assign multiple target action pairs to a gesture recognizer. So to answer your question, I'm not sure how this works when used with the same target/action pair multiple times. It will either not matter, or call the action multiple times in a row. You just have to try.